# Android Studio not notifying for wrong syntax

Tags: android-studio

Presently I am using the updated version 1.0.2 of android studio, it seems to be working fine at all but the issue is when I type a wrong syntax it doesn't notify me with the red color letters mentioning that the syntax written is wrong. Please suggest me where I am lacking, is it in the installation process..?

Answer (score 0):

You must tell AS (Intellij) where your source files are located.
Navigate to: File -> Project settings -> Modules and mark your "src" folder as "Sources"

Comment: thank you for your response, but i am not able to find the path as you mentioned above, I have two possible path in (Intellij).
1. File -> Settings but in settings there is no option named as "Modules"
2. File -> Project Structure -> Modules but there is no folder named as "src"
Thank you